# How can I assign a value to an array in Bash?

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

I am trying to read a list of values from a text file, *hello.txt*, and store them in an array.

```
counter=0

cat hello.txt | while read line; do
 ${Unix_Array[${counter}]}=$line;
 let counter=counter+1;
    echo $counter;
done

echo ${Unix_Array[0]}
echo ${Unix_Array[1]}
echo ${Unix_Array[2]}
```

I am not able to assign values to the array *Unix_Array[]*... The *echo* statement does not print the contents of the array.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are a few syntax errors here, but the clear problem is that the assignments are happening, but [you're in an implied subshell](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#grep_foo_bar_.7C_while_read_-r.3B_do_.28.28count.2B-.2B-.29.29.3B_done). By using a pipe, you've created a subshell for the entire *while* statement. When the *while* statement is done, the subshell exits and your `Unix_Array` ceases to exist.

In this case, the simplest fix is not to use a pipe:

```
counter=0

while read line; do
  Unix_Array[$counter]=$line;
  let counter=counter+1;
  echo $counter;
done < hello.txt

echo ${Unix_Array[0]}
echo ${Unix_Array[1]}
echo ${Unix_Array[2]}
```

By the way, you don't really need the counter. An easier way to write this might be:

```
$ oIFS="$IFS" # Save the old input field separator
$ IFS=$'\n'   # Set the IFS to a newline
$ some_array=($(<hello.txt)) # Splitting on newlines, assign the entire file to an array
$ echo "${some_array[2]}" # Get the third element of the array
c
$ echo "${#some_array[@]}" # Get the length of the array
4
```

Comment: The implied subshell didn't even occur to me.

Comment: **+1**.  Also, note that putting `IFS=$'\n' declare some_array=($(<hello.txt))` all on one line means that you don't have to save `IFS` in `oIFS`.  When used this way, the `IFS` variable is set only for the command line it precedes.  Note that `declare` is the command here; without it, you only have a couple of variable assignments.

Answer (score 9):

If you are using Bash v4 or higher, you can use `mapfile` to accomplish this:

```
mapfile -t Unix_Array < hello.txt
```

Otherwise, this should work:

```
while read -r line; do
   Unix_Array+=("$line")
done < hello.txt
```

Comment: +1 for calling out mapfile. I always forget about the new shell features.

Answer (score 2):

The best way I found is:

```
declare -a JUPYTER_VENV
JUPYTER_VENV+=( "test1" "test2" "test3" )
```

And then consume it with:

```
for jupenv in "${JUPYTER_ENV[@]}"
do
  echo "$jupenv"
done
```

Comment: I think you mean `declare -a`; the uppercase version declares an _assoclative_ array (Bash 4+).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
cat hello.txt | while read line; do
 ${Unix_Array[${counter}]}=$line;
 let counter=counter+1;
    echo $counter;
done
```

You can just do this:

```
Unix_Array=( `cat "hello.txt" `)
```

Comment: Without reassigning `IFS`, this will create multiple elements for any line with a space in it.

Answer (score 0):

It’s a solution:

```
count=0
Unix_Array=($(cat hello.txt))
array_size=$(cat hello.txt | wc -l)
for ((count=0; count < array_size; count++))
do
    echo ${Unix_Array[$count]}
done
```

Comment: This suffers from the same problem as Jon Lin's solution, namely, that you have to set `IFS` to a newline or you'll split on *any* whitespace in `hello.txt`.